# Error exiting do while loop C

Tags: c, do-while, boolean-logic

I wrote a code regarding string input and finding vowels in the string. Everything works fine except the program doesn't exit the do while loop.

```
do{
    i = 0; j = 1;
    str = NULL;
    input = '\0';
    for(l = 0; l < 5; l++ ) { /* initializing arrays with zeros */
        lowercase_vowel[l] = 0;
        uppercase_vowel[l] = 0;
    }
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); /* allocating space for a character in str */
    printf("\nEnter String : ");
    while(input != '\n' ) /* until user press enter */
        {
            input = getc(stdin); /* taking the input */
            str = (char*)realloc(str,j*sizeof(char)); /* re-allocate memory for character read to be stored */
            str[i] = input;  /* store read character */
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    str[i]='\0';   /* appending null character to the string */

    /*Some calculations here */
    printf("\nDo you want to continure? (Y / N)");
    scanf("%c", &option);
 }while( (option != 'N') || (option != 'n') );
```

The problem is that the loop doesn't end when I give the options and also it skips the part

```
 printf("\nEnter String : ");
```

and just calculates according to the value in option. I would really appreciate if someone helped me in this problem

Comment: your code also has undefined behaviour - it does not allocate space for the `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

The condition

```
(option != 'N') || (option != 'n')
```

Is always true for any given value of `option`. You need to replace the `||` (or) with an `&&` (and).